# React, Javascript - Capture browser/tab close event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `beforeunload` event handler to capture the browser close event. I am getting a pop up which shows '`leave`' and '`cancel`' option. Is there a way to capture the 'leave' button click event? I want to trigger a functionality is user clicks on 'leave' on that pop up.

Answer (score 0):

```
const useLeave => {
    const [leaveState, setLeaveState] = useState(false);
    const unloadCallback = useCallback((event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let res = window.confirm('Leave? Really?’)
        setLeaveState(res)
    }, [leaveState]);
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', unloadCallback);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', unloadCallback)
        };
    }, []);

    return leaveState;
};
```

Comment: Please kindly include some comment for your answer. It will help other users to better understand your code.

Comment: Made a generic hook, replace setstate with callback passed to the hook if you want more specific functionality.